# Reactjs having problems printing out fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

super noob question. However, I've been stuck with this issue for long enough now. I've been searching and have found the similar issue but have not been able to resolve it. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong.

I am fetching data from an API, and I am able to log out the array, however, when I try to print it out I am having no luck. In the beginning, I was passing it through a reducer but then realized that was not ideal. Right now I am trying to get it to work, then I'll refactor the code into a functional component.

```js
fetchOrders = async () => {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/ordenes').then( res => {
            this.setState({
                prescription: res.data
            })
        })
    }
```

```js
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.prescription)
        return (
            <div >
                <Paper style={styles.orderCard}id='orderCardContainer' >
                    <div id="profileCardContainer" style={styles.profileCard}>
                        <aside className='profileCardContainer'>
                            <ProfileCard />
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                        {this.renderOrder()}
                </Paper>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The array I receive back from the API looks something like this:

```js
Array(18)
0: {order: Array(3), _id: "5b2af38fb315eb5630a0bc78", physicianName: "Alejandro", patientName: "Alex", createdAt: "2018-06-21T00:38:39.376Z", …}
```

**UPDATE:**

```js
class OrderCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { prescription: []}
    }

    fetchOrders = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/ordenes')
        this.setState({
            prescription: res.data
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchOrders()
    }

    renderOrder() {
        if (this.state.prescription.length === 0 ) {
            return ( 
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                this.state.prescription.map( (x, i) => {
                    <li>
                        {console.log(x.patientName)}
                        <h1>{ x.patientName }</h1>
                    </li>
            })
        )}
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.prescription)
        return (
            <div >
                <Paper style={styles.orderCard}id='orderCardContainer' >
                    <div id="profileCardContainer" style={styles.profileCard}>
                        <aside className='profileCardContainer'>
                            <ProfileCard />
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                    <div id='orders' >
                        { this.renderOrder() }
                    </div>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.auth.authenticated,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(OrderCard)
```

**BACKEND SCHEMA**

```js
const orderObj = new Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
 }, { _id : false })

const orderSchema = new Schema (
    {
        physicianName: String,
        patientName: String,
        order: {type: [orderObj]}
    }, 
    { 
        timestamps: true
    }
)
```

**POSTMAN API RESULTS**

```js
[
    {
        "order": [
            {
                "name": "Asteraceae",
                "price": 41.24
            },
            {
                "name": "Liliaceae",
                "price": 39.24
            },
            {
                "name": "Fabaceae",
                "price": 34.91
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5b2af38fb315eb5630a0bc78",
        "physicianName": "Alejandro",
        "patientName": "Alex",
        "createdAt": "2018-06-21T00:38:39.376Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T00:38:39.376Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance for tips.

Comment: Can you please share the entire code for the component. Specifically how are you calling the fetchOrders method. Thanks.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora Just updated my question with how fetchOrders is being Called. Thanks for your response!

Comment: How is your API structure? I mean how "ordenes" look like? Also, do not use forEach for looping your data. Use map instead, this creates an array and your data will be visible. But at least with forEach your console.log should work and you should see the right data if everything is ok.

Comment: @devserkan "Ordenes" is an array of objects such that: Array(18)
0: {order: Array(3), _id: "5b2af38fb315eb5630a0bc78", physicianName: "Alejandro", patientName: "Alex", createdAt: "2018-06-21T00:38:39.376Z", …}. Each object contains patientName (string), physicianName(string), order(array), created_at and objectID. Currently I am trying to at least just print out patientName which is not as nested

Comment: What do you see in your console.log then? Can you share the whole or a part of API structure instead of what do you get?

Comment: @devserkan I updated my post with the schema structure and a postman result example, hope this help. Thanks!

Comment: So, it is just an array with one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong brackets, you're not returning react element, try fixed one.

```
renderOrder() {
    if (this.state.prescription.length === 0 ) {
        return ( 
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            this.state.prescription.map((x, i) => (
                <li>
                    {console.log(x.patientName)}
                    <h1>{ x.patientName }</h1>
                </li>
        ))
    )}
}
```

and fix this

```
fetchOrders = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/ordenes');
  this.setState({
    prescription: res.data
  });
}
```

Comment: hmm not sure I follow. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: when you use '(x, i) => {<li></li>}' it's not returning anything, but if you're using '(x,i) => (<li></li>)' it's returning <li> element. So you're getting just console log and not <li>s

Comment: You can't get li's with forEach, console.log is ok but JSX element is not. forEach does not return anything, it does something for each loop.

Comment: oops sorry my fault, fixed, tsk abi :)

Comment: Got it! Amazing Thank you guys! I learned so much right now! @devserkan

Comment: Ok then. @OrkhanJafarov I think you should add your async/await suggestion into this answer as a bonus and delete the other one. Also, we don't need `i` here for map :) just an element is enough. x or whatever it is. Btw, you are welcome. you have done most of the job :)

Comment: @devserkan will do sir! Thanks for the positive feedback!